# Proxying variables in Python

Tags: python, class, proxy

I have a Python object that I want to shield from any inside and outside access and run every request through a proxy. I used [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/) piece of code so far which works fine. I subclass it and initialise it with the object I want to proxy.

Unfortunately, it does not cover the case for which access occurs from within the proxied object.

```
class A(object):
    def do_something(self):
       self.foo.perform_action()

class MyProxy(Proxy):    
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(MyProxy, self).__init__(obj)
        self.proxy_foo = ProxyFoo(obj.foo)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item == 'foo':
           return self.proxy_foo
        return super(MyProxy, self).__getattribute__(item)

a = A()
myproxy = Proxy(a)
# do_something should work on proxy_foo, but it operates on a.foo
myproxy.do_something()
```

What can I do to change this?

Comment: Did you override __setattr__  for the proxy?

Comment: Nope. But in my actual example, the call is more like `self.foo.do_something_else()`. I had a breakpoint in `__getattribute__`, but it never actually stopped in the condition to return `proxy_foo`.

Comment: How is your 'Proxy' class defined?

Comment: @NickBailey: I think he's using the Proxy class from the link he gave.

Comment: I think doing this is going to be unsafe, or at least very confusing.  The only way to make `self.foo` inside an A method not set `a.foo` would to pass some other object as `self`.  But if you pass the proxy object as `self`, then `self.foo = 123` will again call the proxy attribute setter, which will again try to set the attribute on the underlying object.  Everything that `a` does with itself will lead to big chains of proxy calls.  A proxy is only supposed to proxy operations that are done on the proxy; trying to mess with `a`'s internal operations is likely to lead to problems.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for your comment. You have a valid point with your comment on the big chains of proxy calls. Especially since `if item == 'foo': return self.proxy_foo` would actually return another proxy that proxies `foo`. There may be other things that need to be proxied from the `foo` object... I might flatten the call hierarchy and use methods on `A` to mutate `foo` and other object rather than returning them and allowing mutations to occur without `A` "knowing" about it...

Comment: Incidentally, your example doesn't really make sense, since you're overriding `__getattribute__` but the `do_something` method is *setting* the attribute.  Which one do you want to override?  If you want to override setting, what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want `self.foo = 123` to access `foo` from the proxy. I don't want to override the whole `do_something` method of `A`, just the data it's working on.

Comment: @orange: `self.foo = 123` does not access (i.e., get the value of) `self.foo`, it just sets it.  Do you want it to set it on the proxy?  If so, `__getattribute__` will not be involved at all.

Comment: Ok. I agree, my example was too simple. `foo` is actually another object (I thought it would require the same handling). I'll modify the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is a good idea.  The only way I can think of would be to catch the access of `do_something` and return a modified bound method with a different `self` object.  This will be at best confusing and at worst broken, because it means that when A tries to access itself, it won't really be accessing itself, but the proxy.  You can do this with your current proxy class, but you have to intercept access to `do_something`, not `foo`:

```
class MyProxy(Proxy):    
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(MyProxy, self).__init__(obj)
        self.proxy_foo = 999

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        #print("__getattribute__({}, {})".format(self, item))
        if item == 'foo':
            return self.proxy_foo
        if item == 'do_something':
            return functools.partial(object.__getattribute__(self, '_obj').__class__.do_something, self)
        return super(MyProxy, self).__getattribute__(item)

a = A()
myproxy = MyProxy(a)
```

Then:

```
>>> myproxy.do_something()
999
```

This only works at all because that Proxy class even proxies the `__class__` attribute, causing the proxy to masquerade as an instance of the proxied class.  Even so, it means that `myproxy.do_something()` results in four separate calls to `__getattribute__`, as you can see if you uncomment that print (one to get `do_something`, an internally-generated lookup of `__class__`, one to get `foo`, and one more for `proxy_foo`).  You can see that if you were calling a method that actually did anything with any attributes, the number of calls could quickly grow.  Also, it's not clear to me that it would even work for all cases (e.g., classmethods, double-underscore private class-level variables).  There could even conceivably be corner cases where it would enter an infinite loop.

In general, proxies are meant to provide a way to substitute one object for another within some enclosing operation that makes use of the object.  Trying to fool an object into believing it itself is some other object is a dicey proposition.  You might be better off making a mixin proxy class that has its own `__getattribute__` doing the proxying you want, and then making a subclass that mixes that with A and using an instance of that instead of an instance of A.  It depends what you're trying to achieve with this proxy.

Comment: Thanks again for your insights. As I already mentioned, I might go with another design that is less confusing.